# Google unit test Set up by default

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I am making a unit test system with google unit test in C++. And I noticed that all my set up of the unit test contain the same line, and all my tears down contain other line, equal for all.

I wonder if there is any way to create a set up by default to be called before the actual set up of the any unit test.

```
#include <gtest.h>
class TestExample : ::testing::Test
{
    public:
        virtual void SetUp ()
        {
            //same line for all tests of my system
            my_system::clean_system();

            //code of specific setup
            //...
        }
        virtual void TearDown ()
        {
            //Code of specific teardown
            //...

            my_system::clean_system();
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Wrapper class i.e. `TestWrapper`, in which you define the default `SetUp()` and call to the  `CustomSetUp()`

```
#include <gtest.h>

class TestWrapper: public ::testing::Test
{
    public:
        virtual void CustomSetUp() {}
        virtual void SetUp ()
        {
            //same line for all tests of my system
            my_system::clean_system();

            CustomSetUp(); //code of specific setup
        }
};
```

Then use `TestWrapper` class in your unit test instead of `::testing::Test` and overload `CustomSetUp()` instead of `SetUp()`

```
class TestExample : public TestWrapper
{
    public:
        virtual void CustomSetUp ()
        {
            //code of specific setup
            //...
        }
        virtual void TearDown ()
        {
            //Code of specific teardown
            //...

            my_system::clean_system();
        }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I thought something like that, but I asked this question to know if exists some method inside google test, to set a pointer function to call before set up or something similar, and don't left the programmer skip this step. But, thank you, anyway, I will do the wrapper.^^